# How to center an image in navigationBar across all UIViewControllers? Swift / Obj-C

Tags: ios, swift

Problem visually:

[image: Logo is centered in the empty space, not in the navigationBar]

I have tried putting the image in the center of its own frame with no luck. I have also tried to center it with playing the `x` of the CGRect with no luck either. I presume I can just put an empty icon with the same background as the navigation bar; however, I don't want to do it that way. I might have 2-3 icons on the right; then what?

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "some_logo")!
    let imageSize = CGSizeMake(60, 42)
    let marginX: CGFloat = (self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.width / 2) - (imageSize.width / 2)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: marginX, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

I prefer swift but obj-c solutions are welcomed as well.

Any pointers appreciated.

This app has nothing to do with KIA, it is just some logo I got off the google search, searching "some logo".

Comment: ooops. I forgot. thanx, code added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created an extension for solving this problem using the hint of @idrougge.

In order to center the title view image no matter what buttons you have, a content view is set as title view, then the image view is added as child of the content view. Finally, using constraints the image view is aligned inside its parent (content view).

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {

    func addLogoToNavigationBarItem() {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <your_height>).isActive = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = <your_image>
        //imageView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        // In order to center the title view image no matter what buttons there are, do not set the
        // image view as title view, because it doesn't work. If there is only one button, the image
        // will not be aligned. Instead, a content view is set as title view, then the image view is
        // added as child of the content view. Finally, using constraints the image view is aligned
        // inside its parent.
        let contentView = UIView()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = contentView
        self.navigationItem.titleView?.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone,

Xavi

Comment: This works until you segue to another view and then return to the main view. When you return it resets and moves off center again

Answer (score 13):

I have faced the same issue. Then i tried one code shown below.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    let image = UIImage(named: "googlePlus")
    imageView.image = image

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
  }
```

This Code working fine when i tested with Left & Right Bar Button.

But in my previous code there is no Right Bar Button.

So the image is moving towards right.

For solving this i created a Right Bar Button & change the Tint color to clear color.

So everything seems to be working fine. This is one Temporary Solution for your problem.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way of doing this is in Interface Builder.

Simply drag a 'NavigationItem' from the object library and place it into your ViewController, then place a UIView where the title goes (ensure you set the background to 'clear')
Then place a UIImageView into that view and set the image in the Attributes Inspector to your required image. Scale your UIImage accordingly and set your your constraints accordingly.

Comment: This also works programmatically. Create an UIView with the prerequisite size and add it as `navigationItem.titleView`, then `navigationItem.titleView?.addSubview(imageView)`. For some reason, it doesn't work if directly inserting an UIImageView as the `titleView`.

Comment: Be aware this won't work if the image is too large. I had an over sized image and this didn't appear to work, got a smaller image and this solution then worked

Answer (score 2):

As question heading stated "Swift / Obj-C" so I am sharing code of Obj-C :

```
UIImageView *titleImage = (UIImageView *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
titleImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width/2) - (100/2), 0, 100,self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];

//setting the image for UIImageView
titleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someLogo"];
titleImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImage;
```

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue on phones with smaller sizes. Image in title was moving to right. Causing this issue back button -> [back_button][title_view]. Its centered when there is no back button or there is right bar button. Richard Hope's was right, you just need to put UIView first, and then put UIImageView as subview. Programmatically could be done like this.

```
private var imageView: UIView {

    let bannerWidth = navigationBar.frame.size.width * 0.5 // 0.5 its multiplier to get correct image width
    let bannerHeight = navigationBar.frame.size.height

    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)

    let image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

    view.addSubview(imageView)

    return view
}
```

The just change titleView

```
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the center of your image equals to the navigationBar.center instead of setting a margin?

```
//assuming we already have our navigationController
let myNicelLogoWidth = 100
let myNiceLogoHeight = 50
//start positioning your logo at 0.0, 0.0
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myNicelLogoWidth, height: myNiceLogoHeight))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.center = navigationBar.center //the put your image at the center

let image = UIImage(named: "myNiceLogoImage")
imageView.image = image


navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: `navigationController.navigationBar.center`

Comment: Does not work, because the entire `center` is offset by the navbar buttons: 
`navigationBar.frame: (0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 44.0)`
`navigationBar.center: (160.0, 42.0)`

Answer (score 0):

I once face with this problem, and finally i found out that the problem is the previous navigation bar title still located next to burger button, but it's invisible.

Fast solution but not sure if it's the best is to change the previous navigation bar title to empty string before show the next view controller.

Hope it's help.